# What kind of kick is this?

Tags: kicking, spinning-kicks, identification

I saw this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LR2S0radfzk

And I wondered, `what kind of kick is this?` so I did some research and I think its a "Tornado Roundhouse Kick", but it doesnt look quite right.

The kid is spinning counter-clockwise into his left side, but ends up kicking with his left foot.

Is it a Tornado Roundhouse Kick or is it something else?

Comment: Sadly, the video no longer exists. :-(

Comment: "This video has been removed for violating YouTube's Community Guidelines." :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely not a tornado kick (dolgae chagi, 돌개 차기). It has a number of names, Americans tend to use wheel kick, in Korea it's more commonly known as a back whip kick and in the UK we tend to use one of "reverse turning kick" or "back hook kick".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a spinning wheel kick to me.

Comment: Yes, I think youre right. Its a spinning wheel kick, with a little extra pre-step.